# Using FB.ui to share on facebook redirects to facebook games?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the following code to share a link on facebook:

```
shareOnFB: function() {
var img = "image.jpg";
var desc = "your caption here";
var title = 'your title here';
var link = 'https://your.link.here/';

// Open FB share popup
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
            'og:url': link,
            'og:title': title,
            'og:description': desc,
            'og:image': img
        }
    })
},
function (response) {
    // Action after response
});
```

with actual working images and links of course. But, clicking on the shared image on facebook redirects to Facebook Games for some reason, and not to the actual link I've provided. What is going on?

Comment: that´s just some workaround, you should use the FB.ui share dialog instead, it automatically takes the open graph data from the url. i assume that facebook does not want people to circumvent this.

Comment: And what is the actual link?